# How do I reconcile a pre-payment on a credit card in Quickbooks?

Tags: credit-card, quickbooks, reconciling

I have two payments to credit card for the same period. One is tied to last month's reconciliation but the other one is just a prepayment because I wanted to charge the account over my limit, so I prepaid the credit card.

I am trying to reconcile this month but only one payment shows in the reconciliation. How do I record the pre-payment in Quickbooks so that it shows in the reconciliation this month?